# Changing logging format for one handler changes it for all

Tags: python, python-logging

I want to stream a logger to several streams. Changing the standard format works, but changing the  `formatException` function changes it for all!
Not sure if it is a feature and I am misunderstanding something.

See example below, where I use the standard logging.Formatter and a modified one with an `limit` variable:

```
import logging, io, traceback


class TermFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, stack_limit=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)    
        self.stack_limit = stack_limit
    
    def formatException(self, ei):
        """
        Format and return the specified exception information as a string.

        This default implementation just uses
        traceback.print_exception()
        """
        sio = io.StringIO()
        tb = ei[2]
        # See issues #9427, #1553375. Commented out for now.
        #if getattr(self, 'fullstack', False):
        #    traceback.print_stack(tb.tb_frame.f_back, file=sio)
        traceback.print_exception(ei[0], ei[1], tb, self.stack_limit, sio)
        s = sio.getvalue()
        sio.close()
        if s[-1:] == "\n":
            s = s[:-1]
        if self.stack_limit ==0:
            return "Hello my friend!"
        else:
            return s
        


stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler.terminator = "  \n"


formatter0 = TermFormatter("F1 %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
                           stack_limit=2)

stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter0)
stream_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)



#check the internals of the err logging

stream_handler2 = logging.StreamHandler()
stream_handler2.terminator = "  \n"
formatter = TermFormatter("F2 %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s",
                          stack_limit=0)
stream_handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
stream_handler2.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


term_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
term_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("F3 %(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s"))
term_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


logger=  logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(stream_handler2)
logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
logger.addHandler(term_handler)

logger.error('wow!')

try:
    raise Exception('oh bad')
except:
    logger.exception("very ugly")
```

output :

```
F2 2021-07-04 14:16:42,889 [ERROR]: wow!  
F1 2021-07-04 14:16:42,889 [ERROR]: wow!  
F3 2021-07-04 14:16:42,889 [ERROR]: wow!
F2 2021-07-04 14:16:42,890 [ERROR]: very ugly
Hello my friend!  
F1 2021-07-04 14:16:42,890 [ERROR]: very ugly
Hello my friend!  
F3 2021-07-04 14:16:42,890 [ERROR]: very ugly
Hello my friend!
```

I would have expected in the three last logs: for F1 the stacktrace with a limit of 2, for F2 what is shown, and for F3 the full stack trace as is the default behavior. I get in all cases the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is documented here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html?highlight=exc_text#logging.Formatter.format

"Note that the formatted exception information is cached in attribute exc_text. This is useful because the exception information can be pickled and sent across the wire, but you should be careful if you have more than one Formatter subclass which customizes the formatting of exception information. In this case, you will have to clear the cached value after a formatter has done its formatting, so that the next formatter to handle the event doesn’t use the cached value but recalculates it afresh."

Comment: To make things clearer: `format` should be changed, not `formatException`, and within it either set `record.exc_text` to None or don't change it at all.